# SceneDelegate to ViewController transition via URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

I have an OAuth authorization code workflow that is kicked off by my ViewController and redirects back to my app via a custom URL scheme. The following function in SceneDelgate.swift does get hit correctly upon re-entering the app after completing authorization on the outside app:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    //I am able to get the authorization code and scopes from the URLContexts
}
```

Looking at the URLContexts I can see the data I need returned (and I know how to extract it). My question is how should I go about passing that data onto my ViewController, which when continuing through this SceneDelegate function does look like it returns to??

EDIT:

What I'm trying to achieve is to extract a URL parameter string (authorizationCode) that is located in the URLContexts parameter of the scene() function. I then want to pass that back to my ViewController so that it can handle the remaining work that needs to be done.

Comment: This is too broad. You have not explained what you want to _do_ when the URL comes in, and there are no rules about what you _should_ do. The idea that you think you want to talk to a view controller might be wrong. I've tried to explain a bit further in my answer, but I've had to be vague because the question is vague. — Also please don't combine multiple questions into one. The fact that `viewWillAppear` doesn't get called is normal, so it sounds like you just misunderstood what that event signifies. But that's a different matter entirely.

Comment: @matt tried to describe exactly what I'm trying to achieve in edit, and removed the second question

Comment: Well, to the extent that “I then want to pass that back to my ViewController” adds anything, my answer tells you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at the URLContexts I can see the data I need returned (and I know how to extract it). My question is how should I go about passing that data onto my ViewController, which when continuing through this SceneDelegate function does look like it returns to??

How you respond to the arrival of a URL is completely up to you.

Your view controller hierarchy is sitting in the scene delegate's `window` starting with its `rootViewController`. If the view controller you want to talk to is present, you can talk to it by working your way through the view controller hierarchy.

More ideally, though, you would just store this information somewhere and emit some sort of notification or subscription that your interface would be able to hear and respond to if needed.

Sometimes more drastic behavior is desirable. You might want to respond by displaying a particular scene of your app. In that case you might need to dismantle the entire view controller hierarchy and build it up again to show that scene. It helps to have a good router architecture underlying your app's navigation.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps I have a couple of iOS AppAuth resources that may give you something to compare against.

- [Getting Setup with an iOS AppAuth Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/ios-setup)

This includes a more full featured Swift UI 2 sample that you can run on a simulator:

- [iOS AppAuth Blog Post with Claimed HTTPS Schemes](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview/)

- [iOS AppAuth Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios)